# How can I fix 'ClassNotFoundException' for main class in my Minecraft plugin on Intellij Idea 2023.1.2?

Tags: java, server, minecraft

I'm currently developping a Minecraft Plugin for my server but after updating my intellij Idea to 2023.1.2 Community Edition, but i could not use auto-completion or auto error detectors and my artifact was getting build even if i wrote something that shouldn't work.

After looking on the internet, i found the solution : on the project structure, i set the src folder as a source folder.

Everything was working fine but now when loading my plugin, i get this error :

```
22:26:09] [Server thread/ERROR]: [ModernPluginLoadingStrategy] Could not load plugin 'Fireland.jar' in folder 'plugins'
org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidPluginException: Cannot find main class `fr.byxis.main.Main'
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.<init>(PluginClassLoader.java:78) ~[paper-api-1.19.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at io.papermc.paper.plugin.provider.type.spigot.SpigotPluginProvider.createInstance(SpigotPluginProvider.java:123) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-522]
    at io.papermc.paper.plugin.provider.type.spigot.SpigotPluginProvider.createInstance(SpigotPluginProvider.java:35) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-522]
    at io.papermc.paper.plugin.entrypoint.strategy.modern.ModernPluginLoadingStrategy.loadProviders(ModernPluginLoadingStrategy.java:116) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-522]
    at io.papermc.paper.plugin.storage.SimpleProviderStorage.enter(SimpleProviderStorage.java:39) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-522]
    at io.papermc.paper.plugin.manager.SingularRuntimePluginProviderStorage.enter(SingularRuntimePluginProviderStorage.java:57) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-522]
    at io.papermc.paper.plugin.manager.RuntimePluginEntrypointHandler.enter(RuntimePluginEntrypointHandler.java:40) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-522]
    at io.papermc.paper.plugin.manager.PaperPluginInstanceManager.loadPlugin(PaperPluginInstanceManager.java:118) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-522]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
    at com.rylinaux.plugman.util.PaperPluginUtil.load(PaperPluginUtil.java:407) ~[PlugManX.jar:?]
    at com.rylinaux.plugman.util.PaperPluginUtil.load(PaperPluginUtil.java:364) ~[PlugManX.jar:?]
    at com.rylinaux.plugman.util.PaperPluginUtil.reload(PaperPluginUtil.java:509) ~[PlugManX.jar:?]
    at com.rylinaux.plugman.command.ReloadCommand.execute(ReloadCommand.java:125) ~[PlugManX.jar:?]
    at com.rylinaux.plugman.PlugManCommandHandler.onCommand(PlugManCommandHandler.java:97) ~[PlugManX.jar:?]
    at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:45) ~[paper-api-1.19.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:155) ~[paper-api-1.19.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_19_R3.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:906) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-522]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_19_R3.command.BukkitCommandWrapper.run(BukkitCommandWrapper.java:64) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-522]
    at com.mojang.brigadier.CommandDispatcher.execute(CommandDispatcher.java:264) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.commands.Commands.performCommand(Commands.java:322) ~[?:?]
    at net.minecraft.commands.Commands.performCommand(Commands.java:306) ~[?:?]
    at net.minecraft.server.network.ServerGamePacketListenerImpl.performChatCommand(ServerGamePacketListenerImpl.java:2290) ~[?:?]
    at net.minecraft.server.network.ServerGamePacketListenerImpl.lambda$handleChatCommand$20(ServerGamePacketListenerImpl.java:2250) ~[?:?]
    at net.minecraft.util.thread.BlockableEventLoop.lambda$submitAsync$0(BlockableEventLoop.java:59) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1768) ~[?:?]
    at net.minecraft.server.TickTask.run(TickTask.java:18) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-522]
    at net.minecraft.util.thread.BlockableEventLoop.doRunTask(BlockableEventLoop.java:153) ~[?:?]
    at net.minecraft.util.thread.ReentrantBlockableEventLoop.doRunTask(ReentrantBlockableEventLoop.java:24) ~[?:?]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.doRunTask(MinecraftServer.java:1342) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-522]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.d(MinecraftServer.java:197) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-522]
    at net.minecraft.util.thread.BlockableEventLoop.pollTask(BlockableEventLoop.java:126) ~[?:?]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.pollTaskInternal(MinecraftServer.java:1319) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-522]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.pollTask(MinecraftServer.java:1312) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-522]
    at net.minecraft.util.thread.BlockableEventLoop.managedBlock(BlockableEventLoop.java:136) ~[?:?]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.waitUntilNextTick(MinecraftServer.java:1290) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-522]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.runServer(MinecraftServer.java:1178) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-522]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.lambda$spin$0(MinecraftServer.java:320) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-522]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fr.byxis.main.Main
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.loadClass0(PluginClassLoader.java:183) ~[paper-api-1.19.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:150) ~[paper-api-1.19.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.<init>(PluginClassLoader.java:76) ~[paper-api-1.19.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    ... 40 more
```

I use the Plugman plugin that isn't the issue.

Here is my plugin.yml

```
name: Fireland
version: 3.0
author: Byxis
main: fr.byxis.main.Main
api-version: 1.19
...
```

And a screenshot of my project in intellij idea (i think that the problem is something about somes folders should be sources and others not etc...)

[image: here]

Thanks in advance for your help,
Consider that i'm still a beginner

Byxis

I tried changing sources folders and some things like this but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

Maven has a standardised project structure. You need to stick to it, to provide a correct bundled jar.

```
└───maven-project
    ├───pom.xml
    ├───README.txt
    ├───NOTICE.txt
    ├───LICENSE.txt
    └───src
        ├───main
        │   ├───java
        │   ├───resources
        │   ├───filters
        │   └───webapp
        ├───test
        │   ├───java
        │   ├───resources
        │   └───filters
        ├───it
        ├───site
        └───assembly
```

(from https://www.baeldung.com/maven-directory-structure)

After setting the project in the correct structure you can configure IntelliJ to flag the directories the right way.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of work, I decided to create another project and copy all of mine in it and it does fix all my problems.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).